# JavaFX .jar not working (Error occurred during initialization of boot layer)

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable-jar

In my IDE (IntelliJ) the program runs without any issues. I tried creating a JavaFX .jar through the IDE and it doesn't work, but that seems to be a known compatibility issue between JavaFX and JDK 11.

After this, I tried creating a normal .jar and executing it via the command below:

```
java --module-path "C:\Users\nerla\Desktop\Coding\JavaFX_SDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx-swt,javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web -jar "C:\Users\nerla\Desktop\Uni\Programming II\Mathdoku\out\artifacts\Mathdoku_jar\Mathdoku.jar"
```

It still doesn't work and produces the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx-swt not found
```

Comment: Are you using module `javafx-swt`? That is part of the SWT library, if not mistaken...

Comment: Java 7 comes in built with javafx but it was removed from later versions

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Yes, I'm using javafx-swt

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues getting JARs created with JavaFX 11 to work.

The fix was to:

- create an additional main method in a class which doesn't extend application and simply calls your real main method.
- include the .so files in the JAR.

To do that in IntelliJ, it's:

File > Project Structure > Artifacts > click the "+" symbol > File > and then select all the .so files in the JavaFX folder.